# Chrome Extension Manifest 'Matches'

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying my hands at a simple Chrome Extension, but am running into a problem with providing a value for the `matches` array in my `content_scripts`.

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My Extension Experiment",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Ext",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": {
    "matches": ["http://*"],
    "js": ["scripts.js"]
  }
}
```

When I try to load this extension into Chrome, I get the following message:

> Could not load extension from 'C:\Users\foo\Desktop\Extensions\bar'.
> Invalid value for 'content_scripts'.

I cannot see what is "invalid" about my value though. What I'm trying to do is match every URL, so my extension can manipulate the DOM (via javascript within `scripts.js`) of any page it is ran on. Am I missing something, going about this all wrong, or what?

**update**

After posting this question, I did notice that the Google example was slightly different than mine, so I modified my code a bit to reflect their syntax:

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["http://*"],
  "js": ["scripts.js"]
}]
```

That being said, I still get the following error when trying to load my extension:

> Could not load extension from 'C:\Users\foo\Desktop\Extensions\bar'.
>   Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]'.

Comment: I was receiving same error but I havne't write `"matches"` key .
where do I see the chrome developer documentation which are required field while creating `content_scripts`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You need to surround the value of the `content_scripts` field in square brackets:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
  "matches": ["http://*"],
  "js": ["scripts.js"]
} ]
```

(see the [Chrome Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for more info)

Incidentally, using `http://*/*` would be a better match for all urls (see the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)), adding `https://*/*` if you also need to match those as well.

**Edit:**

Following your edit, the error you are getting is because of the match pattern being incorrect.

Comment: I saw the `http://*/*` pattern, but was worried that this would require urls to have a `/` after the `http://` in order for my extension to run. Is this incorrect?

Comment: The docs page on pattern matching (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) explain it in detail. All extensions I have seen use the `http://*/*` pattern without issue.

Comment: Yes. I saw this page just moments before asking my question. But their example shows `http://*/*` as matching `http://www.google.com/` which caused me to believe that a url must have a forward-slash after those associated with `http://` in order to invoke my extension logic.

Comment: Try it and see - I believe it will work for both `http://site.com` and `http://site.com/`

Comment: Sure enough, it ended up being the pattern. Thank you, Adrian.

Comment: what about for edge extensions manifest files?

Answer (score 86):

If you want to match every URL, then Google has a special pattern just for this purpose: `<all_urls>`

Sample usage:

```
"matches": ["<all_urls>"],
```

See this page for more info:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

Comment: Very cool, I hadn't known about that. For those looking for the relevant documentation though, the link is actually: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html

Comment: All links to code.google.com in the chosen answer and all comments before this one are broken following a site reorg. I've fixed the chosen answer itself with working links.

Answer (score 11):

Any match pattern should be of the following structure [scheme]**://**[host][path]

1. **scheme** is '*' | 'http' | 'https' | 'file' | 'ftp'
2. **host** is '*' | '*.' (any char except '/' and '*')+
3. **path** is '/' (any chars)

For matching any HTTP/S and FILE URL use:

```
 "matches": [
    "*://*/*",
    "file://*/*"
  ],
```

Ref: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns

By the way, in order to allow access to local files - add the permission:

```
"permissions": [
   "file://*/*"
]
```

Or approve file access on the extension settings page.

Comment: In order to be able to access local files - you need to enable it in chrome settings.

Answer (score 4):

For many that are getting errors involving:

```
'content_scripts[0].matches' is missing or invalid.
```

or

```
'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Empty path.
```

Trying filling in, or *creating*, the matches field with your specific URL needed.
If you want to use all URLs, then use the `<all_urls>` tag like below.

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": [ "jquery.js" ]
        }
    ]
```

Files listed in the "js" array have their path relative to you app. 
In other words, the location of "manifest.json" is your root directory.

*Note: jquery.js is a file in my project's directory and you should replace it with whatever script file you want.*

Answer (score 3):

After many tries following working , it matches all URL's and also supports http & https.enter code here

```
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "content_scripts": [
    {
     "matches": [
        "*://*/*",
      ]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery on a CDN, Just download it and include it to your working folder, And then try to import it

Answer (score -4):

Bro you forgot to add

"manifest_version":2

Which is mandatory one.

Comment: The question is from 2010; back then, `manifest_version` did not exist yet.