# Module Load Progress Events in NaCl with manifest_version = 2 and no inline javascript

Tags: javascript, module, google-chrome-extension, embed, google-nativeclient

I upgraded my manifest_version to "2" as per [this document](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html), and then was suprised to see chrome burping up errors like:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

While it is clear why they would do this, I am now unclear how i should be managing Module load [progress events](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/coding/progress-events). Even if i ratchet it to the latest (dev) pepper release, the documentation is still recommending an inline script (which obviously doesn't work).

I am a bit frustrated (after spending a weekend afternoon coding up a module load with progress) to see this version flip and render my stuff completely invalid.

So, yeah...it is for the greater good. I understand. But now i have to have a standalone javascript file (with its own load paradigm) and hook up to the `<embed/>` element in time to catch events correctly? What is the new and improved method for doing this now?

Can anyone suggest a reliable alternative to this sanctioned boilerplate?

Comment: I understand that this is the only allowed javascript mechanism for the new manifest_version, and i understand the underlying issue (the answer to the "duplicate" question). My question is not what is wrong with the old way...but rather what is the (new and recommended) way to use an external javascript file and never miss a `<embed/>` load event for the nacl module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation for NaCl progress events](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/coding/progress-events#HandlingEvents), event listeners have to be added as follows:

```
<div id="listener">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('listener').addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Example
    }, true);
  </script>
  <embed name="nacl_module" ... type="application/x-nacl" />
</div>
```

This if **forbidden** by the Content security policy ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10417745)). There's only one way to solve it: By moving the script to an external file:

```
<div id="listener">
  <script src="listener-load.js"></script>
  <embed name="nacl_module" ... type="application/x-nacl" />
</div>

// listener-load.js:
document.getElementById('listener').addEventListener('load', ..., true);
```

Because the construction of the DOM blocks until the external file is loaded, the script is loaded before the `<embed>` tag is inserted. Since the external files are packaged with the extension, the impact on performance can be neglected.

Comment: The piece I was missing was the "construction of the DOM blocks until the external file is loaded" part (I haven't done much js work, so i was assuming the external file had to be in the `<head/>` and missed that i could still have the `<script/>` tag inline). Thanks for explaining not only _how_ to do this, but also _why_ it will be a suitable solution. Much appreciated.