# Chrome extension .json file error when uploading

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a `manifest.json` file like this:

```
{
  "name": "YouTube Trending to Paid promotion!",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Change Trending to Paid promotion!",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "*://*.youtube.*/*"],
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.youtube.*/*"],
      "js": ["popup.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

For my JS extension that just finds the 41st `<span>` and renames the contents. And when I inject it directly, it works fine. But when I try to upload it, Chrome gives me this error message: `Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Invalid host wildcard.`

My JS is following:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[39].textContent="Paid promotion!";
```

Anyone got an idea whats causing the error ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as the error states, is that your `matches` value is invalid.  The [Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) documentation explains that `*`, when used in the host portion, has the following requirements:

> `*` in the host can be followed only by a `.` or `/`
>   If `*` is in the host, it must be the first character

Thus, your match pattern of:

```
"matches": ["*://*.youtube.*/*"],
```

is invalid because the second `*` (`youtube.*`) is not permitted.

### Explicitly list the Top Level Domains (TLDs) you desire to match

You need to explicitly determine the TLDs you desire to match, then include a list of them in your `matches` array. For example:

```
"matches": [
    "*://*.youtube.com/*",
    "*://*.youtube.co.uk/*"
],
```

However, for YouTube, they appear to redirect all traffic to `youtube.com`.  Thus, you are probably just fine using:

```
"matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
```

This matching limitation is by design. There are a [large number of TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains), and more are likely to be created in the future. There is no guarantee that a particular site which you desire to match currently has a domain in every TLD, nor that they will obtain one in every new TLD which is created. Thus, the better solution is to not permit wildcards for the TLD when a portion of the host is specified.

### Alternately, use `include_globs`, but then have possible false matches

You can use [`include_globs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match-patterns-globs) to obtain what you desire, but doing so has security risks due to possible false matches. You would need something like:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["popup.js"],
     "include_globs": [
       "http://*.youtube.*/*",
       "https://*.youtube.*/*"
     ]
  }
]
```

This is still imperfect, as it will match URLs which contain `.youtube.*/*` anywhere in their URL (e.g. `http://foo.example.com/clone/www.youtube.com/myVideo`). Unfortunately, because `include_globs` is a glob, not a full regular expression, you can not specify that you want to match all characters but `/`, which you could do in a regular expression (e.g. `[^/]`).  Overall, you are better off explicitly determining the TLDs you desire to match, then include a list of them in your `matches` array.

Note: In the above example, your `matches` pattern could be either `"*://*/*"`, or `"<all_urls>"`. The difference is that `"<all_urls>"` also matches "file:" and "ftp:" URLs, which are then excluded by the `include_globs`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems Content Script matches are slightly different.

See the matterns are allowed in chrome https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["popup.js"]
    }
  ]
```

or use `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]`

Refer : [Chrome Extension Manifest 'Matches'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769525/chrome-extension-manifest-matches) already discussed by stackoverflow.